# OrientDB - Update with SUBSELECT

Tags: orientdb

I want to update some rows of my table basing on other rows of the same table:

I try this:

```
UPDATE MyTable set myField = 
    (SELECT T1.myField
    FROM MyTable T1
    WHERE T1.id.substring(start,stop) = MyTable.id.substring(start,stop))
```

But OrientDB throws an error like this:

`com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandSQLParsingException: Error on parsing command at position #XXX: Invalid keyword 'T1' Command:`

Comment: does Orient need the AS keyword?  FROM MyTable AS T1 ?

Comment: Dear, with or without AS Orient returns an error

Comment: I don't see table alias mentioned at all in the docs.  Try w/o the alias if you have a sec, just typing out MyTable.

Comment: Without alias how can I say to Orient engine how to resolve ambigous field?

Comment: I am going to give this a shot in Orient in the next hour and let you know what I find.  But in MySQL for instance, you can do this:  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS update_me;
CREATE TABLE update_me
( id int, body text, subbody text)
;

INSERT INTO update_me (id, body) VALUES
 (1, "this is my first row")
, (2, "this is my second row")
;

UPDATE update_me set subbody = substring(body, 11, 19);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all you in OrientDB you can't use Alias on Classes.

In this case you could use $parent.$current in a subquery, something like:

```
> update MyTable set myField = (
>         select myField
>         from MyTable
>         where myField is null
>         and id.substring(8,13) = $parent.$current.id.substring(8,13) and something else...
>          ) where myField is null and something else...
```

Be careful to the length of the id...

Best Regards
M.

Comment: where did you find informations about $parent.$current keywords?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a string update, but an integer update in place.  Using the provided GratefulDeadDatabase, you can do:

```
CONNECT remote:localhost/GratefulDeadConcerts;
SELECT performances FROM v;
----+------+------------
#   |@CLASS|performances
----+------+------------
0   |null  |null        
1   |null  |5           
2   |null  |1           
3   |null  |531         
4   |null  |394         
----+------+------------

UPDATE v SET performances = eval('performances + 2') WHERE performances IS NOT NULL;
SELECT performances FROM v;
----+------+------------
#   |@CLASS|performances
----+------+------------
0   |null  |null        
1   |null  |7           
2   |null  |3           
3   |null  |533         
4   |null  |396         
----+------+------------
```

So the update works on the data in place. I'm fairly new to OrientDB so maybe an expert can tell me if I just did something horribly horribly wrong.

UPDATE

Notice that in your example you are updating the table with values from the same table.  That is, from MyTable into MyTable (unless I misunderstood your query) and even within the same row.  You can use criteria on the WHERE clause to only update rows of interest.  In my example, that was

```
WHERE performances IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Dear, my question is on subquery. Where the subquery on your answer?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I don't believe it is necessary.  You are trying to update a table with values from the same table, so you should not need a subquery.